# "Non-standard syntax" error with vectors in function arguments

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ though I know some Java, and I was trying to make a program that finds prime numbers and prints them, but instead of testing whether n is prime by doing n%m for all integers m smaller than n and testing whether it's 0, it only tests whether the modulus with the primes it has already found is 0, since it gives the same result but maybe a bit more efficiently (though I might be completely wrong about the efficiency, I wanted to do it more as an exercise). The issue I am facing is that it throws an "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member" error, which I'm not sure what it means. I only know the very basics of pointers so idk how to fix this and what the issue is exactly.

I already tried throwing a bunch of '&' signs in various places before the vectors, hoping to make it work by accident but I couldn't figure it out. Here's the code I have right now:

```cpp
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(vector<int> list, int number);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);

    for (int m = 3; m <= n; m=m+2)
    {
        if (isPrime(primes, m))
        {
            primes.push_back(m);
        }
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < n; m++)
    {
        cout << primes[m];
    }
}

bool isPrime(vector<int> list, int number)
{   
    int l = list.size;
    bool isPrime = true;

    for (int n = 0; n < l; n++)
    {
        if (number % list[n] == 0) 
        {
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }

    return isPrime;
}
```

And here is the error message:

> non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member with [_Ty=int]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is kind of confusing.

The issue is that `std::vector::size` is actually a function, not a data member.

Thus, to call it, you need parenthesis:

```
int l = list.size();
```

I will admit, though. The compiler error isn't too explanatory. It stems from the fact that functions can be treated as pointers if you use them without the parenthesis. That's useful for things like storing callbacks. But that's not what you're doing here, so you simply want to call the function.

Comment: So that's why it didn't actually tell me I missed the parentheses. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If either of our answers solved your problem, feel free to accept one of them by clicking the check mark next to the answer. If both solved your issue, then feel free to select the best one.

Comment: I vote for your answer, you explain the issue a lot better than I did.

Comment: Well thank you. If it makes you feel better, I voted for yours too. It's quick and to the point, though admittedly lacking in a deeper explanation. That's why I added my answer too.

Answer (score 4):

To call a function in C++, you need to use the `()` symbols.

```
int l = list.size();
```

Comment: Huh, that's odd, it didn't highlight it as an error... Thanks, it worked, though now it gives me another error, something about a vector subscript being out of range, but at least that one is fixed.

Comment: The code you linked above compiles in VS2019 when you change that line as I indicated (and add the `#include`s you omitted). What line is the compiler complaining about?

Comment: I figured it out, it did compile, it just complained after I tried to run it because the for loop that printed the results went up to n instead of the actual size of the vector.